# Deleting elements from link list(through recursion)

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

Now the problem here is that it's working for every value except first and ones those do not exist in the list... The program returns a garbage value and crashes. (Trying to do via recursion btw)

```
bool deleteValue(student *head, int id) {
    student *curr, *prev;
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        curr = head->next;
        prev = head;
        if ((curr->data == id) && (curr->next != NULL))
        {
            prev->next = curr->next;
            delete(curr);
            return true;
        }
        if (head->data == id)
        {
            student *temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }
        if ((curr->data == id) && (curr->next == NULL))
        {
            delete head->next;
            head->next = NULL;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return deleteValue(head->next, id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}     // function
   // delete

cout << "Student has ";
if (deleteValue(head, 15) == true) {
    cout << "been ";
}
else {
    cout << "not been ";
}
cout << "deleted. ";
print(head); // function being called
```

Comment: Also, upon entering value that doesn't exist in the list it crashes.

Comment: " simply crashes returning a garbage value" does it crash or does it return a garbage value? How can it do both?

Comment: @tobi303 it returns a junk value "-1352642642" then it crashes.

Comment: Have you even tried debugging your code? This code has manu issues: after `delete curr;` `head->next` still points on `curr`, etc.

Comment: @VTT I've looked all over stackoverflow and this is what is used to delete the head node and appoint a new one...

Comment: Additional issue is that when you delete head, the previous node which pointed to that head becomes invalid.

Comment: it is ok to copy and paste code from somewhere, but do yourself a favour and try to understand it before you use it. Even answers on SO are not always free of bugs or maybe the answer that you used does not apply in your case

Comment: @AlexLop. Are you talking about the "curr" and "prev"?

Comment: @tobi303 I did all of this through recursion myself except deleting the first node which wasn't working through my methods so I tried the internet...

Comment: @abdullah no, I am talking about `if (head->data == id)`.let's say you are deleting the 3rd node. Where will the `next` of the **second** node point?

Comment: @AlexLop. This is the function posing problems(I already know), and this one is only used for deleting the first node... becomes invalid for nodes after the first one... The problem is I can't get to delete the first node...

Comment: @abdullah it doesn't necessarily delete the first node sine it is recursion. Head maybe the middle node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool deleteValue(student *head, int id) {
student *curr, *prev;
if (head != NULL)
{
    curr = head->next;
    prev = head;
    if (curr!=NULL && curr->data == id && (curr->next != NULL)) //check whether curr is NULL or not NULL
    {
        prev->next = curr->next;
        delete(curr);
        return true;
    }
    if (head->data == id)
    {
        student *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        return true;
    }
    if (curr!=NULL && (curr->data == id) && (curr->next == NULL)) //even here check for NULL
    {
        delete head->next;
        head->next = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return deleteValue(head->next, id);
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```